# cannot change the main title and x, y labels for plot() of boot() result

Tags: r, plot, statistics-bootstrap

I am new to R but have had some practice labelling plots so I thought this would be the same for the result from a bootstrap using `boot()`.

```
#question 7
library(boot)
# function to obtain mean of x
fc <- function(x, indices){
  dt <- x[indices]
  c(mean(dt))
}
set.seed(123)
mybootstrap <- boot(x, fc, R=1000)
head(mybootstrap)
plot(mybootstrap, index=1,main="Boostrap mean of x", xlab="mean", ylab="density")
```

But actually it is giving me the generic "Histogram of t" and xlab of "t*" rather than what I wrote in the brackets to specify these things.  Why is this so?

Comment: t* is the stats you are trying to estimate for each bootstrap. mybootstrap$t0 is mean from your original dataset, mybootstrap$t is the mean estimate for the 1000 bootstraps and the histogram you just saw, is hist(mybootstrap$t)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not easy to adjust the plot settings in `boot`.  Best is to pull out `t` and use `plot` with `freq=F` to get a density plot:

```
 hist(mybootstrap$t, freq = FALSE, breaks = 50,
     main="Boostrap mean of x", xlab="mean", ylab="density")
```

[image]